# Micro-Econ Question | Price Elasticity and demand changes

Tags: economics

3. You sell car insurance to low-income consumers. You have the cheapest rates in Texas—just $30 per month—and you have 100,000 identical customers. You estimate that the price elasticity of demand for your insurance is - 0.1.

________    a. If you raise your prices by 10% or $3 what percent of your customers will you lose?

________    b. How many customers will you lose?

________    c. Your total monthly revenue will change by what percent? (Include + or – sign.)

________    d. Your total monthly revenue will change by what $ amount? (Include + or – sign.)

Comment: Have you looked up the definition of price elasticity of demand?  What did you find?  You need to plug the given values into the definition to answer these.